Questions about SIS hard problem
The definition of $\mathrm{SIS}_{q,n,m,\beta}$ problem is as below.

Let $A\in\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times m}$ be an $n\times m$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ that consists of $m$ uniformly random vectors $\boldsymbol{a_i}\in\mathbb{Z}_q^n{:}A=[\boldsymbol{a_1}|\cdots|\boldsymbol{a_m}]$. Find a nonzero vector $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^m$ such that for some norm $\|\cdot\|:$
$\begin{aligned}&\bullet0<\|\boldsymbol{x}\|\leq\beta,
\bullet f_A(\boldsymbol{x}):=A\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{0}\in\mathbb{Z}_q^n.\end{aligned}$.

My questions are:

If $n=m$, the full rank matrix $A$ does not have null space, then $x$ is identity zero vector. In such case, is the SIS problem nonsense?
If $n<m$, we can employ null space algorithms to get a set of basis vectors $B$, then does the short integer solution $x\in Span(B)$?



full rank matrix

$A$ is not full rank automatically. It is only full rank with high probability. This is easiest to see by considering $n = m = q = 2$.
Fully half of the matrices of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $a,b,c,d\in\{0,1\}$ are singular. For larger $n,m,q$ the probability a uniformly random (square) matrix is singular becomes very small, but it is not 0 for any choice of parameters.

we can employ null space algorithms to get a set of basis vectors $B$, then does the short integer solution $x\in\mathsf{span}(B)$?

Your question is not entirely clear. $x \in \ker A$ by construction. It appears if you are asking if $B$ is a basis for the subspace $\ker A$, then is $x\in\ker A$ in $\mathsf{span}(B)$? The answer is trivially yes, but this has nothing to do with SIS, and is instead just a basic linear-algebraic fact.

Thank you for your response. I am new to lattice-based cryptography, so there may be errors in my questions. Restating the first question: If $A$ is a full rank square matrix, does the SIS problem become irrelevant in such a condition?

I create a new question about the continuation of this question.
